# How can I find and change zero-values row/column intersection in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

How can I find rows and columns with all zeros, then get the intersection to input 1 (row 12 and column 11 should be changed to 1 due to intersection) and if there is no intersection, skip this process?

Input:

```
uvv=np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

My attempt:

```
m1 = ~uvv.any(axis=1)  # rows with all zeroes
m2 = ~uvv.any(axis=0)  # columns with all zeroes

rows = np.nonzero(m1)[0]  # find rows to fill
cols = np.nonzero(m2)[0]  # find available columns
```

Comment: Could there be multiple cross intersections ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.all()` with `axis=1` to find rows with all zeroes (all_zero_rows) and `axis=0` to find columns with all zeroes (all_zero_columns).

If both `any(all_zero_rows)` and `any(all_zero_columns)` are `true`, it means there's an intersection and then we can use `np.where()` to find the row and column indices with all zeroes.

```
import numpy as np

uvv= np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


all_zero_rows = np.all(uvv == 0, axis=1)
all_zero_columns = np.all(uvv == 0, axis=0)

# Check if there is any intersection
if any(all_zero_rows) and any(all_zero_columns):
    zero_row_indices = np.where(all_zero_rows)[0]
    zero_column_indices = np.where(all_zero_columns)[0]

    # Change the intersection elements to 1
    uvv[zero_row_indices[:, np.newaxis], zero_column_indices] = 1

print(uvv)
```

Answer (score 1):

To find and fill all possible cross intersections between zeroed rows and zeroed columns use [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to get coordinate matrices along with [`np.stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) + `np.reshape` to get an array of pairs representing all intersection points.

Extended sample with 3 zeroed rows and 3 zeroed columns:

```
uvv = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

---

```
m1 = ~uvv.any(1)  # zeroed rows flag
m2 = ~uvv.any(0)  # zeroed columns flag
if m1.any() and m2.any():
    ind = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(np.nonzero(m1)[0], np.nonzero(m2)[0])).reshape(-1, 2)
    uvv[ind[:, 0], ind[:, 1]] = 1
    print(uvv)
```

---

```
[[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```